# Host Pappa is deleting all my data and websites because it found malware. Isn't there anything I can do?

Tags: web-hosting, malware

I am in South Africa, and Host Pappa has been hosting my domains, sub domains, and emails now for about 6 months.

I received an email from support Host Pappa that they found malware on my account.  It is their policy to wipe my entire account (including all 6 of websites). I do not have a say in the matter, I cannot get into my CPanel account, I can actually do nothing.
In the email I am told to say YES to a number of questions – The questions saying that I understand that I am to lose all my websites, I am to lose all my data bases, I am to lose all my emails – it seems once they reset I am too lose everything
So hours of work, thousands upon thousands of rands spent, I am just to accept and lose everything.

Is there anything I can do?  Is there anybody in America that I can report this too.   ANYTHING move them if I have to would be great.

Comment: Don't tell me you don't have backups of your sites?

Comment: I feel for you! Your host should be helping you clean-up whatever malware issue exists and not beating you up over it. These things happen. It is a part of doing business on the web- though to be avoided of course. Can you call them and see if they can help you rid your site of the malware? It would make sense that they should help you with this and not lose a customer.

Comment: I agree with @closetnoc , It is good that your hosting company alert you about malware. You can say them to allow you to backup/download all files , databases and all. If they do not support to remove malware then you can easily hire any developer/freelancer to do that task and once all malware looks clear then you can again upload files to run your sites.

Comment: I agree but they will not even allow me to do that - my account is suspended, next step Host Pappa says is they need to reset the account which means I lose everything

Comment: And I am sure me being in South Africa they do not really care about losing lil ole me.................

Comment: Word for the day is ephemeral and that is what digital content is without backups. It's a heartbreaker...

Comment: Your location has little to do with it, it is in their hosting agreement and from a legal perspective, you willingly accepted those terms. Many hosting providers in America have similar clauses, why do you not have backups of your work? This is the most basic, elementary rule in computing: Always have backups.

Answer (score 3):

If that is their policy as spelled out in their hosting agreement, then you probably have little legal recourse.

In the future, I would recommend creating regular backups of your websites.  This isn't the only way to lose your data.   There could be hardware failures.   Hosts can go out of business.

As the policy is draconian and not customer friendly, I would give the host bad reviews on hosting review websites.